# xampp not reading the arabic element of select populated form the database

Tags: php, xampp

[image: attached the screenshot of the problem these are arabic]

the fixed element of another select is working fine 
[image]

and it's working normally on apache and wamp

Comment: What character set and collation is set for both databases from your examples? Do they differ?

Comment: Can you elaborate as to the difference between the two? there must be something different about the pages / queries / echos :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what extension are you using to connect to the DB? if it's mysql(), try:

```
mysql_set_charset("UTF-8", $db_link);
```

Right after the link declaration, assuming you store the data as UTF-8 :)

Comment: I have fond the problem it's because htmlentities(<?php echo $var ?>)